# Connect to a FTP from shell script and get the last 14 files from the folder

Tags: linux, shell, ftp, get

How do we connect to a FTP from a shell script and pull the last 14 (or n) modified files by timestamp and place them on one of the folders from the current host. I try to use

> mget

, but can we specify to get the files based on the timestamp and the number of files to get... Please advise... Thanks in advance...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598071/linux-script-to-automate-ftp-operation

Answer (score 1):

You can define an `ftp` macro (`macdef`) and automate your login (in your `~/.netrc` file) and in youe script fetch a file listing; sort the listing by date with `awk` or `sort -k` in your  script to build a list of `N` files that you want to fetch; then simply loop through the list and fire up ftp to fetch them.

It might be easier to use [`curl`](http://curl.haxx.se/). and probably would more portable to use something like `perl` and [`Net::FTP`](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aFTP).